# Windows in Virtualbox show error Ex80070057 when copying files from a network share

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I encountered this problem after installing 13.04. Windows virtual machine was originally installed on an 10.04 system.

I could not open any files on network shares (shared from the host machine), and when I tried to copy the files to the Windows guest system, I got the error Ex80070057: The parameter is incorrect. Question was: how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the solution was simple: I had to re-install the guest add-ons of Virtualbox and restart the Windows guest. The problem went away.